# XCode 4.5 watchpoints not working

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, lldb, watchpoint

I'm trying to debug C++ code in Xcode 4.5 on iOS, running the app on a connected iPad 2.

I set a regular breakpoint on my code, and when I hit it, I look at my Local variables, click on a variable and select "Watch xxxxx".

The lldb console shows:

> error: failed to create watchpoint for m_step

Same result if I try to set it by hand in the console, with the command:

> w s v xxxxx

I get:

> error: Wathpoint creation failed (addr=0x..... size=4)
>   error: sending gdb watchpoint packet failed

I'm running with a debug configuration, using LLDB. Any clue whether there is something else I should check?

**EDIT**: here are my settings:

[image: settings]
[image: settings]
[image: settings]

Comment: You say you're using lldb but the error message says "sending gdb watchpoint packet failed".  Perhaps lldb uses the same protocol; not sure.  Check your project settings anyway.

Comment: I added screenshots of the project settings

Comment: Does it work if you use gdb instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What iOS is your iPad 2 running?  Watchpoint support requires a debug server included in iOS 6, not earlier versions.  It sounds like the debug server running on your device does not have watchpoint support.  The device-side debug server is fixed with the iOS build, it doesn't get updated by Xcode.  Watchpoint support in Xcode 4.5 involved changes to both the device-side debug server (in iOS 6) and changes to lldb in Xcode on the Mac.  Both sides are required for this feature.

Comment: Yep, the iOS version is lower than 6

Answer (score 1):

The latest Xcode release notes says that Xcode 4.5 supports them.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/00-Introduction/Introduction.html

Well... so what? (That's a rhetorical question, by the way.) I couldn't get watchpoints to work on Xcode 4.5 either! I suspect they just don't work. Still.